# how to express this position in English: "to put your feet up"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at these pictures

[image]

and

[image]

People often put one of their lower legs and rest it on the thigh of the other leg.

Sometimes, that action is just **his habit**, but it could be that he want to **relax when he does like that**.

> [put one's feet up](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1229&bih=565&ei=vUAgXvO8DanxhwOdvZ3ACg&q=define%3A%20put%20your%20feet%20up&oq=define%3A%20put%20your%20feet%20up&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l10.119984.125636..126015...0.1..0.223.2570.15j7j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i273j0i131j0j0i67j0i70i249j0i22i10i30.iCdMZ0CTMCE&ved=0ahUKEwizj92e-ofnAhWp-GEKHZ1eB6gQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)
>
> phrase of foot INFORMAL
>
> take a rest, especially when reclining with one's feet raised and
>   supported.

---

am not sure "**put your feet up**" is a good one to use in this case?

Note: I found this in the dictionary

> [**cross–legged**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/cross-legged%20) /ˈkrɑːsˌlɛgəd/  adjective Learner's definition of
>   CROSS–LEGGED : having the legs crossed
>
> She curled up into a cross-legged position.
>
> — cross–legged adverb
>
> She sat cross-legged.
>
> The kids sat on the floor cross-legged. [=with their legs crossed and
>   their knees spread wide apart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "to put your feet up" doesn't describe this position but your question has actually been asked and answered in a post on English Language & Use:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237000/how-would-you-call-sitting-with-your-legs-crossed-but-one-calf-resting-on-the-ot

Take a look. It answers your question :)

Comment: do we say "to lie with crossed legs"?

Comment: We can do, but that might be  understood to mean lying with the legs extended and crossed - see  [this article on tomb effigies](the-history-girls.blogspot.com/2016/02/cross-your-legs-and-hope-to-die-what.html)  . I don't think the pose in your picture is common enough to have a simple  name in everyday language, though yoga experts might have a name for it.

Comment: Sorry about the above - I could not get the link to post properly.